# Assigning an integer value to unsigned char

Tags: c++, ascii

Trying to understand, but I am not able to get the perfect answer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    unsigned char ch = '150';
    int count=0;//just to get a count for the loop
    cout << (int)ch<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= ch * 2; i++){
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        count++;
    }
    cout << count;

    return 0;
}
```

When I am assigning:

```
unsigned char ch = '250';
```

If is printing the same output. What I am understanding from the output is that, it is taking the last index of number i.e 0, and from the ASCII lookup table giving me the integer value as 48 for

```
unsigned char ch = '186';
```

Gives me the integer value as 54,(Which is the ASCII value of number 6)

```
unsigned char ch = '154';
```

Gives me the integer value as 52, (Which is the ASCII value of number 2)

Is my understanding correct? and will this be applicable for any number assigned to unsigned char in single quote?[image: I have attached the screenshot of the Ascii look up table].

I am not getting any error or warnings.[image: No error in the compiler]

Comment: `unsigned char ch = '150';` ??? typo: `unsigned char ch = 150;`

Comment: I am using the visual studio 2015

Comment: The single quote convert an ASCII caracter to it's value. If you want to assign a numerical value, you do it like any other int. a.k.a. `ch=150`

Comment: Doesn't it complain about "*multi-character constant*"?

Comment: I was asked this question in a interview. the numerical value was in single quote

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings? I get *warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'int' to 'unsigned char'*.

Comment: Note that when I define `unsigned int u = '150';` the value printed is `3224880` which in hexadecimal is `313530` which in pairs are the ASCII codes for `1` and `5` and `0` respectively. This value cannot fit `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

No, because you have wrapped the value around single quotes it becomes a *multi-character constant*, and it's value is *implementation defined*, so it has nothing to do with the index of any of the chars, because there are no chars involved.

If you want the value `150`, then

```
unsigned char c = 150;
```

is the way.

The way you have it, it's type is `int` indeed and you cannot store such value in an `unsigned char` strictly speaking, so the compiler might issue a warning for that, and another one for the *multi-character* constant being non-*portable*.

In general, do not ignore warnings unless you knew that the compiler was going to warn about it beforehand, and in such case help the compiler ignore such warning by taking the appropriate action which depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to declare `unsigned char` character literals:

```
unsigned char ch1 = 150;
unsigned char ch2 = 0x96;
unsigned char ch3 = '\150';
unsigned char ch4 = '\x96';
unsigned char ch5 = '\0226';
unsigned char ch6 = 0226;
unsigned char ch7 = 0b10010110;
```

Choose the one which is most readable in your application

if you cast to `int` your var is printed as number, not as character.
If you want character, don't cast

```
cout << ch << endl;
```

Comment: And what about `unsigned char ch5 = 0226`? And it's equivalent `unsigned char ch6 = '\226'`.

Comment: I talked about 'some', not a complete list. However, added some more possibilities, just for you

Answer (score 1):

There's a great difference between:

```
unsigned char ch = '150'; // wrong way
unsigned char ch = 150;   // correct way (conversion from integer to char according to ASCII standard)
```

As you can see i the first line as long as ch is of type char and you assign it a string (multi-char constant). Here no conversion will occur from ASCII to int or the contrary but in face you get a warning from the compiler:

```
warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
```

The correct way is to assign only one character to one character variable:

```
unsigned char ch = '1'; // or any other character.
```

In the second statement:

```
unsigned char ch = 150;
```

Above the value `150` is integer value not a string so the compiler will convert it to character according to ASCII Table which is `û`.

Another example:

```
char ch = 65; // which is capital a `A` in ASCII.
std::cout << ch << std::endl; // A
```